# When to close a MongoDB connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

For context, I am writing an ExpressJS app and using the MongoDB node driver, `mongodb`.

The app will need to talk to the remote DB rapidly at times, depending on how often users are doing things. I understand that the app shouldn't open and close a connection each time it needs data. It should connect once, and there should be an thing named `db` that you can use for querying, example: `db.collection("users").find(...)`, and all future DB calls should just use that  `db` variable.

But if I deploy my app, I am assuming that `server.js` just executes once at the beginning of the app's life. That would mean that one connection is made once in the entire lifespan of that deployment.

But don't these connections time out? Do I just check that the `db` var is an open connection, and if not, reconnect before making a call?

Surprisingly, I haven't found many guides, so I don't know the right way, which is why I am asking here. Please let me know if I can ask this question in a better way.

Answer (score 14):

You don't have to manage the connection yourself. The MongoClient.connect call comes with batteries included. See [the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#~connectCallback): the connect methods includes a `autoReconnect` (defaults to true) which will attempt to keep the connection available. You also have `poolSize` (defaults to 5) to give the client (that you can save and reuse throughout your app) the opportunity to use more than 1 connection.

Adding full example:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(client => runMyApp(client));

function runMyApp(client) {
    // Use client however you like e.g.
    client.db('users').find({})
        .then((results) => console.log(results));
}
```

Comment: So it's true that I don't ever need to write `client.close()`, and I just connect once like this:

`var client = MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => client );`

Comment: Unless you're debugging, testing or creating short running jobs no.

Comment: I don't know why I can't understand this or find guides. Now I am using: `const db = MongoClient.connect(dbURL);` And when I want to do a query, I am doing `db.collection("users").find(...).then(function(docs) {...});`, and I am never using the `.close()` method.

Comment: No because the MongoClient.connect call is asynchronous... you really need to understand asynchrony in JS. YDKJS is a good resource but requires some dedication to reading.

Mongoose is typically the ORM everyone uses for Node, so most blogposts will be based on Mongoose.

I can't get good formatting here, so I'm updating my answer, one sec.

Comment: The key to understanding this is that MongoClient is a library that provides a method called "connect" that asynchronously, (i.e. not instantly), provides you with a reusable "client" object that you can then use to make database calls. Directly assigning var client = MongoClient.connect(url) will assign the client a promise, that you can use to evaluate the reusable client object. You have to understand promises and the event loop though.

Comment: I think the only reason I'm having trouble is that I don't want to have to put the entire app in a callback function. You mean I should even put all my routes in there? I'm looking for a way to assign the "client" to a global variable and use it from anywhere, maybe with a check to see if the connection needs to be re-established before calling. I'm not using Mongoose because I like to do it the hard way to understand why more advanced tools were built.

Comment: Well doing it the hard way means you have to write a lot of boilerplate yourself. So I gave you the simple hard way, but if you want to be able to use the client without putting it in a callback function, you can. There are quite a few different ways of achieving it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179071/discussion-between-user1803096-and-nth-chile).

Comment: @nth-chile: did you find any reason why we should or shouldn't use .close() anywhere in the app (except for cleanup on app termination)? I am facing serious memory leaks which chokes my server to death and I suspect not using .connect() and .close() on every query could be the reason.

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava I don't think you should use `connect` or `close` for each query unless you're using serverless functions. If you are using `connect` but not `close`, I would guess that you should try to remove `connect` from the queries